# How do you sort table columns with Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, crud

I have put together a simple CRUD application and have most of it working but cannot seem to figure out how to sort the table columns. I have a working demo here: http://codepen.io/figaro/pen/MJMqYR

```js
var products = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Angular',
    description: 'Superheroic JavaScript MVW Framework.',
    price: 900
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Ember',
    description: 'A framework for creating ambitious web applications.',
    price: 600
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'React',
    description: 'A JavaScript Library for building user interfaces.',
    price: 500
  }
];

function findProduct(productId) {
  return products[findProductKey(productId)];
};

function findProductKey(productId) {
  for (var key = 0; key < products.length; key++) {
    if (products[key].id == productId) {
      return key;
    }
  }
};

var sortable = Vue.extend({
  data: {
    sortKey: 'name',

    reverse: false,

  }
})

var List = Vue.extend({
  template: '#product-list',
  data: function() {
    return {
      products: products,
      searchKey: ''
    };
  }
});

var Product = Vue.extend({
  template: '#product',
  data: function() {
    return {
      product: findProduct(this.$route.params.product_id)
    };
  }
});

var ProductEdit = Vue.extend({
  template: '#product-edit',
  data: function() {
    return {
      product: findProduct(this.$route.params.product_id)
    };
  },
  methods: {
    updateProduct: function() {
      var product = this.$get('product');
      products[findProductKey(product.id)] = {
        id: product.id,
        name: product.name,
        description: product.description,
        price: product.price
      };
      router.go('/');
    }
  }
});

var ProductDelete = Vue.extend({
  template: '#product-delete',
  data: function() {
    return {
      product: findProduct(this.$route.params.product_id)
    };
  },
  methods: {
    deleteProduct: function() {
      products.splice(findProductKey(this.$route.params.product_id), 1);
      router.go('/');
    }
  }
});

var AddProduct = Vue.extend({
  template: '#add-product',
  data: function() {
    return {
      product: {
        name: '',
        description: '',
        price: ''
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    createProduct: function() {
      var product = this.$get('product');
      products.push({
        id: Math.random().toString().split('.')[1],
        name: product.name,
        description: product.description,
        price: product.price
      });
      router.go('/');
    }
  }
});

var router = new VueRouter();
router.map({
    '/': {
      component: List
    },
    '/product/:product_id': {
      component: Product,
      name: 'product'
    },
    '/add-product': {
      component: AddProduct
    },
    '/product/:product_id/edit': {
      component: ProductEdit,
      name: 'product-edit'
    },
    '/product/:product_id/delete': {
      component: ProductDelete,
      name: 'product-delete'
    }
  })
  .start(Vue.extend({}), '#app');
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>School Application</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">

    <header class="page-header">
      <div class="branding">

        <h2>School Application</h2>
      </div>
    </header>
    <main id="app">
      <router-view></router-view>
    </main>
  </div>


  <template id="product-list">
      <div class="actions">
        <a class="btn btn-default" v-link="{path: '/add-product'}">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
          Add new entry
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="filters row">
        <div class="form-group col-sm-3">

          <input v-model="searchKey" class="form-control"placeholder="Search..." id="search-element" requred/>
        </div>
      </div>
      <table class="table highlight bordered">
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Description</th>
          <th>Price</th>
          <th class="col-sm-2">Actions</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr v-for="product in products | filterBy searchKey in 'name'">
          <td>
            <a v-link="{name: 'product', params: {product_id: product.id}}">{{ product.name }}</a>
          </td>
          <td>{{ product.description }}</td>
          <td>
            {{ product.price }}
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-euro" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <a class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" v-link="{name: 'product-edit', params: {product_id: product.id}}">Edit</a>
            <a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" v-link="{name: 'product-delete', params: {product_id: product.id}}">Delete</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </template>

  <template id="add-product">
      <h3>Add new product</h3>
      <form v-on:submit="createProduct">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="add-name">Name</label>
          <input class="form-control" id="add-name" v-model="product.name" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="add-description">Description</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" id="add-description" rows="10" v-model="product.description"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="add-price">Price, <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-euro"></span></label>
          <input type="number" class="form-control" id="add-price" v-model="product.price"/>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
        <a v-link="'/'" class="btn btn-default btn-danger">Cancel</a>
      </form>
    </template>

  <template id="product">
      <h2>{{ product.name }}</h2>
      <b>Description: </b>
      <div>{{ product.description }}</div>
      <b>Price:</b>
      <div>{{ product.price }}<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-euro"></span></div>
      <br/>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <a v-link="'/'">Back to product list</a>
    </template>

  <template id="product-edit">
      <h2>Edit product</h2>
      <form v-on:submit="updateProduct">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="edit-name">Name</label>
          <input class="form-control" id="edit-name" v-model="product.name" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">

        </div><div class="form-group">
          <label for="edit-description">Description</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" id="edit-description" rows="3" v-model="product.description"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="edit-price">Price, <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-euro"></span></label>
          <input type="number" class="form-control" id="edit-price" v-model="product.price"/>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
        <a v-link="'/'" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</a>
      </form>
    </template>

  <template id="product-delete">
      <h2>Delete product {{ product.name }}</h2>
      <form v-on:submit="deleteProduct">
        <p>The action cannot be undone.</p>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
        <a v-link="'/'" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</a>
      </form>
    </template>

</body>

</html>
```

I do apologize if this is simple, I just don't understand what I am missing.

Comment: I don't see where you are using `sortable`?(´･_･`)

Comment: I dont know how to make sortable do what I named it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should create a computed property e.g. sortedData and you should do simple Javascript sorting :

```
computed: {
  sortedData: function() {
     return this.data.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.name > b.name;
     });
  }
}
```

Then you should use the computed property in your list.

---

Comment: and how would that be implemented?

Comment: I've written how it's done. If you want more concrete implementation create a jsfiddle and I will show you. The products and the methods should be part of the Vue instance and you should use sortedData in the v-for.

Comment: I have a case where my data (array of objects) is switched up/down when some object values change ... but wanna keep the rows fixed!

Comment: Not sure if `sort()` with a comparison inside is the right way. I had to do something like `a.id - b.id` to get it working rather than `a.id > b.id`